# cocos2dx and some kind of image cache

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am playing around with cocos2dx in Xcode and developing for iphone. My question concerns the creation of sprites from png images stored in the Resources folder. Images load and everything works good until I remove, say, mysprite.png from the Resources folder. cocos2d should give me some kind of error like file not found but it compiles well! And even loads mysprite.png somehow. It seems like the sprite I removed is still stored somewhere in some kind of cache. If one such cache exists, how can I clear that cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not because of cache. When Xcode compiles a project and creates an app bundle, it copies all the resources in the directory (which results in addition of all new resources and replacement of all the modified ones in that bundle but doesn't delete the resources that have been removed).

You can remove app from Simulator or your iPhone so that next time when the app is installed, the newly built app won't have resources that have been removed.